# C# save Excel worksheet as html and read this html

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

in my project I need to save user customized excel to .mht file and immediately reload the file into memory, code is following

```
var app = new Excel.Application();   
var wsCurrent = app.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
object format = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWebArchive;
var codename = application.ActiveSheet.CodeName; 

wsCurrent.SaveAs(outputFile, format, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

however, I found that due to the natural of excel, ince we save the file, it will lock the process until the excel application closed. in other word, I could not load the saved .mht file unless I close excel which I do not want to, 
any one better idea to do this and please give me a clue to the solution, 
many thanks in advance, 
cheers,

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a workbook variable equal to `Application.Activeworkbook`, save the activesheet of this object and then call close on the workbook, Excel can remain open, like so:

```
var app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet wsCurrent = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.XlFileFormat format = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWebArchive;

wsCurrent.SaveAs(@"C:\test\test.xlsx", format);

workbook.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks JMK it does works, however, due to I don't want close orginal instance of worksheet so,  application.Worksheets.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing); will give me the answer